# What would cause a ```.``` output using the %in% function, R?

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I have written some code to tell me which RSIDs are matching between some databases using the `%in%` function. It has worked well up until this point where it is returning `.` instead of the RSID#. If I have two data.frames

```
df1 <- data.frame (
rsID = c("rs1", "rs2", "rs4"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(
rsID = c("rs1", "rs4", "rs8"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I use the `%in%` function to give me the matching rsIDs in a data.frame which I use to extract additional information from my database of interest. There may be a better way to do this, but this method seems to work.

```
matches.df <- data.frame(
rsID = df1$rsID[(df1$rsID %in% df2$rsID)],
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now up until this point the code would return the two matching rsIDs, "rs1" and "rs4", but for this database it returns `rs1, .`.

Has anyone seen this before, or have insight as to why it is returning a `.`

I can attach images if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't provide an example that reproduces the problem. Hence people can only guess what the problem is. My guess is that the result is correct, but your IDs are incorrect. Maybe there was mistake when reading the data / parsing the ID information from a longer string, or something like that.

Comment: i don't know the answer to your question - but `intersect(df1$rsID , df2$rsID)` will give you the ids present in both.  Even better use `merge` to combine the info from your two data frames.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius thank you for pointing that out to me. The data-set is very large, and I don't know how to create a reproducible example, because I don't know where the ```.``` comes from, since this has worked fine up until this point. My hunch is it has something to do with the data set, and not the code.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva Will a merge line up the matching rsID columns? I had experimented with merge at first, but couldn't avoid Cartesian Join and the rsIDs didn't line up which lead to an extra filter step.

Comment: @Ctat41 you simply should take the dataset in question, and check how `df1$rsID` and `df2$rsID` looks. See if they both have `rs4`, I don't think there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

The column may contain ‘.’  It is a legitimate value. Means NA in vcf.